# How do I find the MIME type of a file with PHP?

Tags: php, filesystems, http-headers, content-type

I have an *index.php* file which has to process many different file types. How do I guess the filetype based on the `REQUEST_URI`?

If I request `http://site/image.jpg`, and all requests redirect through *index.php*, which looks like this

```
<?php
   include('/www/site'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
```

How would I make that work correctly?

Should I test based on the extension of the file requested, or is there a way to get the filetype?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I am hoping you don't really run code like that on your website.

Comment: No, of course this isn't the way it actually works.  That was just the best way to get the point across (so I thought).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are sure you're only ever working with images, you can check out the [exif_imagetype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) PHP function, which attempts to return the image MIME type.

If you don't mind external dependencies, you can also check out the excellent [getID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net) library which can determine the MIME type of many different file types.

Lastly, you can check out the [mime_content_type()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) function - but it has been deprecated for the [Fileinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) PECL extension.

Comment: Instead of getimagesize(), call exif_imagetype() instead: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php .  It provides the same information without the performance penalty of doing other things.

Comment: "The return value is the same value that getimagesize() returns in index 2 but exif_imagetype() is much faster." from the above link as @XiongChiamiov posted

Comment: @leek :how to get mime type for any content .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847663/changing-video-content-type-mime-type-in-cdn-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 23):

*mime_content_type()* is deprecated, so you won't be able to count on it working in the future. There is a "fileinfo" PECL extension, but I haven't heard good things about it.

If you are running on a Unix-like server, you can do the following, which has worked fine for me:

```
$file = escapeshellarg($filename);
$mime = shell_exec("file -bi " . $file);
$filename should probably include the absolute path.
```

Comment: `file` command might be disabled (on shared hosts) for security reasons.

Comment: *I haven't heard good things about it.* - Would nice if we could read what you've heard ;)

Comment: You say `mime_content_type` is deprecated based on what? Doesn't seem deprecated as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php .

Answer (score 18):

```
function get_mime($file) {
  if (function_exists("finfo_file")) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // Return MIME type a la the 'mimetype' extension
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    return $mime;
  } else if (function_exists("mime_content_type")) {
    return mime_content_type($file);
  } else if (!stristr(ini_get("disable_functions"), "shell_exec")) {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/134930/1593459
    $file = escapeshellarg($file);
    $mime = shell_exec("file -bi " . $file);
    return $mime;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

For me, nothing of this works—`mime_content_type` is deprecated, `finfo` is not installed, and `shell_exec` is not allowed.

Answer (score 10):

I actually got fed up by the lack of *standard* MIME sniffing methods in PHP. Install fileinfo... Use deprecated functions... Oh, these work, but only for images! I got fed up of it, so I did some research and found the [WHATWG MIME sniffing specification](http://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/) - I believe this is still a draft specification though.

Anyway, using this specification, I was able to implement a MIME sniffer in PHP. Performance is not an issue. In fact, on my humble machine, I was able to open and sniff thousands of files before PHP timed out.

Here is the [MimeReader class](https://github.com/shanept/MimeSniffer/).

```
require_once("MimeReader.php");

$mime = new MimeReader(<YOUR FILE PATH>);
$mime_type_string = $mime->getType();     // "image/jpeg", etc.
```

Comment: Sounds great! Now it is `Living Standard — Last Updated 11 June 2013`, so not a draft. Did you managed to upload / share somewhere your PHP code using this?

Comment: Hi trejder. Thanks for that update, and sorry for the late reply. You can find all my projects hosted on my mini-site (it's not much, I know). I will probably put it on github if it gets popular. Everything is under projects. It's released to the public domain, so feel free to clean up the code (it needs it!) or otherwise modify as you see fit.

http://shane.social-library.org/

Comment: Hi Syed Qarib, thanks for letting me know. I have updated the link to github, as you suggested.

Comment: This class not have CSV type.

Comment: Correct - that is because CSV files are plain text, this works purely on the magic number so as far as the class is concerned, it is plain text. You should be able to do some checking on these plain text files if you want to distinguish, or please feel free to make a fork. Thanks

Comment: @Shane, it's not working... I'm getting an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method MimeReader::get_type() in /home/***/public_html/editor.php on line 189`

Comment: Hi Tricks for the Web, how old is the version you are using? If you have a recent copy, the API has changed slightly from snake_case to camelCase, so the appropriate function is  now getType. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 8):

If you are working with *images* only and you need a MIME type (e.g., for headers), then this is the fastest and most direct answer:

```
$file = 'path/to/image.jpg';
$image_mime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($file));
```

It will output true image MIME type even if you rename your image file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual, the [finfo-file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function is best way to do this.  However, you will need to install the [FileInfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) PECL extension.

If the extension is not an option, you can use the outdated [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/mime_content_type) function.

Comment: Also. Fileinfo extension is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3

Comment: @Stann No, it is not! `PHP Version 5.4.7` + `Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\...`.

Answer (score 1):

`mime_content_type()` appears to be the way to go, notwithstanding the previous comments saying it is deprecated. It is not  -- or at least this incarnation of `mime_content_type()` is not deprecated, according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php. It is part of the FileInfo extension, but the PHP documentation now tells us it is enabled by default as of PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use finfo to accomplish this as of PHP 5.3:

```
<?php
$info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo $info->file('myImage.jpg');
// prints "image/jpeg"
```

The FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE flag is optional; without it you get a more verbose string for some files; (apparently some image types will return size and colour depth information). Using the FILEINFO_MIME flag returns the mime-type and encoding if available (e.g. image/png; charset=binary or text/x-php; charset=us-ascii). See [this site](https://www.inanimatt.com/php-files.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but there's a [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo) for getting a file's MIME type.  The official documentation for it is in [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

Depending on your purpose, a file extension can be ok, but it's not incredibly reliable since it's so easily changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with images, you can use the `[getimagesize()][1]` function which contains all sorts of information about the image, including the type.

A more general approach would be to use the FileInfo extension from [PECL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

Some people have serious complaints about that extension... so if you run into serious issues or cannot install the extension for some reason you might want to check out the deprecated function [`mime_content_type()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you run Linux and have the extension you could simply read the MIME type from /etc/mime.types by making a hash array. You can then store that in memory and simply call the MIME by array key :)

```
/**
 * Helper function to extract all mime types from the default Linux /etc/mime.types
 */
function get_mime_types() {
    $mime_types = array();
    if (
        file_exists('/etc/mime.types') &&
        ($fh = fopen('/etc/mime.types', 'r')) !== false
    ) {
        while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
            if (!trim($line) || substr($line, 0, 1) === '#') continue;
            $mime_type = preg_split('/\t+/', rtrim($line));
            if (
                is_array($mime_type) &&
                isset($mime_type[0]) && $mime_type[0] &&
                isset($mime_type[1]) && $mime_type[1]
            ) {
                foreach (explode(' ', $mime_type[1]) as $ext) {
                    $mime_types[$ext] = $mime_type[0];
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($fh);
    }
    return $mime_types;
}
```

Comment: What extension? File extension?

Answer (score 0):

The MIME type of any file on your server can be gotten with this:

```
<?php
  function get_mime($file_path){
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type  = $finfo->file(file_path);
  }

  $mime = get_mime('path/to/file.ext');
```

Answer (score -1):

I got very good results using a user function from
http://php.net/manual/de/function.mime-content-type.php
@''john dot howard at prismmg dot com 26-Oct-2009 03:43''

```
function get_mime_type($filename, $mimePath = '../etc') { ...
```

which doesn’t use *finfo*, *exec* or a deprecated function.

It works well also with remote resources!

Comment: This function was **deprecated** long time before you wrote this answer, so proposing this solution is pointless.