# How do I tell if someone's faking a filetype? (PHP)

Tags: php, upload, mime-types, file-type

I'm programming something that allows users to store documents and pictures on a webserver, to be stored and retrieved later.  When users upload files to my server, PHP tells me what filetype it is based on the extension.  However, I'm afraid that users could rename a zip file as somezipfile.png and store it, thus keeping a zip file on my server.  Is there any reasonable way to open an uploaded file and "check" to see if it truly is of the said filetype?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files). If you can read first few bytes of a binary file you can know what kind of file it is.

Comment: Magic numbers are not always at the beginning.  TGA, for example, has them at the end, I believe.

Comment: be aware that by relying on this check, malicious users can insert magic bytes and then write PHP code in the same file to try and execute some code on your machine

Comment: Any examples on how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Check out the [FileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) PECL extension for PHP, which can do the MIME magic lookups for you.

Answer (score 4):

Sort of. Most file types have some bytes reserved for marking them so that you don't have to rely on the extension.  The site http://wotsit.org is a great resource for finding this out for a particular type.

If you are on a unix system, I believe that the file command doesn't rely on the extension, so you could shell out to it if you don't want to write the byte checking code.

For PNG (http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Rationale.html)

The first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the following values:

(decimal)              137  80  78  71  13  10  26  10

(hexadecimal)           89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a

(ASCII C notation)    \211   P   N   G  \r  \n \032 \n

Answer (score 2):

Many filetypes have "[magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files)" at the beginning of the file to identify them,  You can read some bytes from the front of the file and compare them to a list of known magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only dealing with images, then getimagesize() should distinguish a valid image from a fake one.

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(getimagesize("b&n.jpg"));'
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  int(200)
  [1]=>
  int(200)
  [2]=>
  int(2)
  [3]=>
  string(24) "width="200" height="200""
  ["bits"]=>
  int(8)
  ["channels"]=>
  int(3)
  ["mime"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
}

$ php -r 'var_dump(getimagesize("/etc/passwd"));'
bool(false)
```

A false value from getimagesize is not an image.

Answer (score 1):

For an exact answer on how you could quickly do this in PHP, check out this question: [How do I find the mime-type of a file with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php#134893)

Answer (score 1):

As a side note I ran into a similar problem where I had to do my own type checking.  The front end interface to my application was done in flash.  The files were being passed through flash to a php script.  When I was attempting to do a MIME type check using php the type always returned was application/octetstream because it was coming from flash.

I had to implement a magic numbers type paradigm.  I simply created an xml file that held the file type along with some defining patterns found within the beginning of the file. Once the file reached the server I did some pattern matching with the xml file and then accepted or rejected the file. I didn't noticed any real performance decrease either which I was expecting.

This is just a side note to anyone who may be using flash as there front end and trying to type check the file once it is uploaded.

Comment: What method did you use to compare the files to your reference?

Comment: In the xml file I had an attrib of the position where the magic string can be found in the file.  So I read in the specified number of bytes from the file and converted it to hex and did a compare.

Answer (score 1):

As well as identifying the filetype, you might want to watch out for files with other files embedded or appended to them. This will unfortunately require a more indepth analysis of the file contents than just using "magic numbers".

For example, http://quantumrook.wordpress.com/2007/06/06/hide-a-rar-file-in-a-jpg-file/ (this particular type of data hiding can be easily worked around by loading and resaving into a new file the actual image data .. others will be more difficult.)

Answer (score 0):

On a unix system, capturing the output from the 'file' command should provide adequate info.