# Laravel file upload security - It can be hacked

Tags: laravel, security

I can not make safe my upload function.
I can be hacked.

For example;

When I change my PDF raw content to html,
I accepts to upload.

[image]

Here's my upload controller;

```
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'photo' => 'mimes:pdf'
    ]);


    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => error_formatter($validator),
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ]);
    }

    $file = $request->file('photo');

    $allowedMimes = [
        'application/pdf',
    ];

    if(!in_array($file->getMimeType(), $allowedMimes)){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'error.',
            'errors' => $validator->errors(),
        ]);
    }
    
    if(isset($data['photo'])){
        $filename = uniqid().".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filePath = 'uploads';
        Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs($filePath, $file, $filename, ['visibility' => 'public']);
        $event->photo = $filename ?? $event->filename;
    }
```

It saves the file as 123123.html.
And all html content is in it.

How can I stop it to be hacked?

Comment: You shouldn't use `getClientOriginalExtension` in this case. Checking mime type is based on file header, so it's pass validation. You need also validate file extension next to mimes to be sure that only expected files going through. And never and ever allow to execute file uploaded by user.

Comment: How would the code inside the pdf execute? You cannot trust user input, even with checks with [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185236/how-do-i-tell-if-someones-faking-a-filetype-php). Handle all user input as if it has corona.