# PHP, How to get Mime Type - Mission Impossible?

Tags: php, image, get, mime-types

Is there any decent way in PHP to get the mime type?

I have been searching extensively the past few hours and it seems like there are three main ways, which each way having problems:

1. mime_content_type()
   This is deprecated, alot of the times not installed, and if installed will sometimes not find the mime.magic file.
2. file_info
   Wasn't installed on the hosts I tried, doesn't seem to have very good support. Is an extension (PECL).
3. shell_exec(file -ib . $file)
   Doesn't work on windows servers. I tried it on a linux server and it gave me "image/x-3ds2" for a php file. What the hell is that!!!

What is a good, almost bullet proof way to get the mime type of a file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the mime-type of a file with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php)

Comment: Erm, I am abit confused. I read that post actually, but I cant find any good answers, I mean, I cant find any acceptable answers, does it mean, I cant post any similar question in future if there is no absolute answer yet? Whats SO rules? I want to know, so that I can follow =)

Comment: And I think this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php) was asked 1 year ago, I doubt there would be any new answers to it =(

Comment: I use Apache's mime.types to map extensions into mime types.

Comment: What kind of files are you expecting? Images? Specific documents?

Comment: Yep, images. Whitelist file format: jpg, gif and png. Blacklist: php, asp, exe etc

Answer (score 2):

As workaround you can use the "mime.php" extension from http://upgradephp.berlios.de/
It simulates the **mime_content_type()** if not available. Made specifically for such cases.

You can install your private mime.magic file and force it with ini_set("mime_magic.magicfile"). This is recommended anyway, so you have the desired settings available.

Comment: mime.php is unfinished, and i just tested it, it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Chris Jean has developed [a function called `get_file_mime_type`](http://chrisjean.com/2009/02/14/generating-mime-type-in-php-is-not-magic/) that first tries to use the `finfo_open` method, then falls back to the `mime_content_type`, then finally falls back to a simple `extension => mime_type` array.  It works well for me when the first two options were not available on my server.  Beats having to write the function myself!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files), consult some other file signature lists ( [like this one here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) ), and then check the binary data for the first byte .

```
function getfiletype($file) {
    $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
    if (!$handle)
        throw new Exception('File error - Can not open File or file missing');

    $types = array( 'jpeg' => "\xFF\xD8\xFF", 
                    'gif' => 'GIF',
                    'bmp' => 'BM',
                    'tiff' => '\x49\x20\x49',
                    'png' => "\x89\x50\x4e\x47\x0d\x0a",
                    'psd' => '8BPS', 
                    'swf' => 'FWS');

    $bytes = fgets($handle, 8);
    $filetype = 'other';

    foreach ( $types as $type => $header ) {
        if ( strpos( $bytes, $header ) === 0) {
            $filetype = $type;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    return $filetype;
}
```

This is actually a very simple replacement function for file_info(), which operates in much the same way but on a much extended ( and lower ) level .

Alternative is using an already made external php class like [this one](https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3) for example ..