# how to access other file type through php

Tags: php

im considering to create a resource file in php to read other file type??

for instance, instead of calling the image / javascript directly, i shall pass a query string to this resource.php indicating the type of file, and it would perform the same function as it is originally.

for instance:
using `resource.php?type=js&file=alertme.js` which would read alertme.js that alert("hello world");

Comment: Sounds like you just want to output the contents of the given filename to the browser in which case I'd go with @deceze's answer. You have to be *EXTREMELY CAREFUL* when doing this with filenames supplied externally though since this can open your site to directory traversal attacks. e.g. Someone could go to resource.php?file=resource.php and see the source code of your script. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal . Edit: @alex's answer is a bit more comprehensive if that is indeed what you were asking.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want..

#### resource.php

```
<?php

if ( ! isset($_GET['type']) OR ! isset($_GET['file'])) {
   die('missing params');
}

$type = $_GET['type'];
$file = $_GET['file'];

if ( ! $file = realpath($file)) {
    die('file does not exist');
}

// Make sure the path does not go above our specific folder
$maxParentFolder = '/home/user/public_html/';

if ( ! preg_match('/^' . preg_quote($maxParentFolder, '/') . '/', $file)) {
   die('invalid path');
}

$mime = getMimeByExt($type);

header('Content-Type: ' . $mime);

readfile($file);
```

You need a function to get MIME types. [Look here for further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php).

Also, if `type` will always be the same as the file extension, you can omit it and get the extension using `$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)`.

Also, `die()` isn't the most useful error reporting. I have used it here just for an example.

Comment: Checking for "illegal" characters in the filename may not be sufficient to protect against path traversal attacks, and it may actually be desirable to allow relative paths. Use `realpath` and appropriate path checks instead.

Comment: @deceze Yep, I thought that too, so I modified it. If the OP wants to allow relative paths, then they can modify my example. :)

Comment: You're still not using `realpath`. :-P

Comment: @deceze How is that - I think that is what you meant :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what the question is, but perhaps you're looking for [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile)?

Comment: +1 for mention of `readfile()` (I've seen security problems with large open source applications using `include` instead).