# $_files['uploaded_img']['type'] vs getimagesize()

Tags: php

I want check uploading file type, tell please where way is reliable for this, in where case obtain I more exactly info about file type? in this:

```
$_files['uploaded_file']['type']
```

or in this:

```
$imgType = getimagesize($_files['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']);
$imgType['mime'];
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']` is user input - it is an arbitrary string defined by the client. It is therefore not safe to use for anything at all, ever.

`getimagesize()` is a much safer way to do it, but it does not protect you completely.

You also need to:

- Store the file on your local server with a name completely of your own devising. It is not safe to rely on any user input for generating local file system file names.
- Use GD to copy the pixel data from the source file to the destination file. `getimagesize()` only looks at the meta data associated with the file and does not look at the file data. It is possible to hide malicious code inside something that looks like an image. Once you have resampled the image, ensure the uploaded file is deleted from the server.
- Ensure that the file is stored in the local file system with the minimum required permissions and a restrictive owner/group.

Answer (score 3):

`$_FILES[...]['type']` is *never* reliable, it's an arbitrary user-supplied value. `getimagesize`, [`exif_imagetype`](http://php.net/exif_imagetype) or [finfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) are the preferred ways to check what you've got. Also see [Security threats with uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061355/security-threats-with-uploads).

Answer (score 2):

I Trust **getimagesize**

Because  any one can edit the uploaded file type Using any HTTP/HTTPS headers  like  tamper data addons in firefox

Answer (score 1):

In practice you should probably use the meta data that comes with the image, (`$_files['uploaded_file']['type']`), however this could be tampered with before upload.

If you're just after the size, use this as it will be faster than actually measuring the image with `getimagesize`.  However if you are after filetype information, it may be best to check beyond what the file 'says' it is as it's all to easy to sneak an executable through a naive check.

Answer (score 1):

Using `getimagesize()` will provide you with more consistent mime information since it uses it's environment `mime-type` definitions for files (GD module mime database).

If you solely rely on `$_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']`, then it will contain mime-type as defined on client computer (i.e. browser) or browser may not even send mime-type.

One pretty stupid example of this is checking `if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg')`, which may fail when using IE6/7 that will send `'image/pjpeg'` mime-type

An alternative to both of these is using `mime_content_type()` but it is being deprecated as PECL module so as of PHP 5.3.0 there are [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functions that should work much more consistent with any file type - though I haven't tested it.

For more overview of mime-types check this SO article: [How do I find the mime-type of a file with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever trust `$_FILES["image"]["type"]`.  It takes whatever is sent from the browser, so don't trust this for the image type.  so use `getimagesize()` or if you want to be on more safe side use `finfo_open`

Source :http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php