# how to verify an image format with php

Tags: php, image, format

i need to verify a lot of images files for an application, the situations is that i have 10 directories with almost 10,000 images on each one, something like 100,000 files. Those files are supposed to be gif files but a lot of them (and really mean a lot) were jpg files that a designer change the extension from .jpg to .gif without converting the file format. This is causing the application crash, it creates pdf files using those images, and if i tell to the programm that use the file somefile.gif but it really is a jpg with the extension renamed the pdf creator crashes. I don't want to open every file in something like irfanview or photoshop to verify the format and then modify it if is necessary. Is there a library, class, plugin or something in php or another language that tell me the format of files with no base in the extension but in the headers of the file?

I can't find any ideas to do this, some one can help me?

Thanxs a lot in advance!!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php#134893

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally use [exif_imagetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) for a true verification rather than checking extensions or mime types.

Comment: `exif_imagetype` is not for *true* verification. It's even less intensive than `getimagesize` (but quite the same league).

Comment: @M8R-1jmw5r: `exif_imagetype()` reads the first bytes of an image and checks its signature.  Then, using PHP native function, its the best one.

Comment: To distinguish between gif and jpeg maybe, yes. If you also need color-depths etc., it is not that helpful. E.g. the PDF creator might crash with CMYK jpegs ;) Also `getimagesize()` is available even if gdlib is disabled.

Comment: The question was in reference to filetypes. Not color depths. The extra information provided by `getimagesize()` would be most certainly helpful for debugging purposes, but if we're only checking if the file is an actual JPEG or GIF, then exif_imagetype is the most efficient way to perform this check. I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's "not for *true* verification". Can you explain how reading the byte signature of an image file isn't verification?

Comment: thnxs @maiorano84, it really works for me, now knowing the real extension i can manipulate the format with gdlib before using the file with the pdf creator.

Comment: @maiorano84: you can fake byte-signatures of files. Not that `getimagesize` would be *much* better with it, that is having the first X bytes of an image and then add just crap behind it. The image is broken (and can't probably be even loaded, however, the signature looks fine. A *true* verification checks the whole file incl. that the data is not even prepended.

Comment: I don't disagree, but you're splitting hairs. Neither `exif_imagetype` nor `getimagesize` check the *entire* contents of the file for verification. `getimagesize` has its benefits in that it returns quite a bit of information about a given image file. But the way it checks the file itself is nearly identical to `exif_imagetype`. Neither are better, nor are they in different "leagues". They're just different tools for a given job. In this particular case, I would personally use `exif_imagetype` simply because the only information we want is in regards to the filetype. Nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find out between gif or jpeg, the function `getimagesize()` can do that for you. See http://php.net/getimagesize.

```
list(,,$imageType) = getimagesize($path);
if ($imageType === IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    // GIF found
}
```