# Is $_FILES['type'] set by client or server?

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

#### Question:

Does $_FILES[...]['type'] come straight through from client or does PHP / Apache set this value?

#### Why I am askin this:

This one just popped up while writing upload script that should check for uploaded file types, I already have code for checking uploaded file mime type but do I need that code?

#### Some code related to question:

Here's what I currently got (*simplified*) in uploaded file validation method, this should check that uploaded file's type is really what client claims it to be:

```php
// Get temporary file and mime type
$src  = $file["tmp_name"];
$mime = $file['type'];

// Get real file mime type, this does not guarantee that file is valid
$finfo = new finfo();
$file_mime = $finfo->file( $src, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE );
unset($finfo);

// Test mime types against each other
if ($file_mime === $http_mime)
    return true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the [PHP documentatio](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)n, this information comes from the browser :

> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information.
>   An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked
>   on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

However, as stated by the docs and the other comments on your question, you don't wan't to be very confident on this information : some browsers just don't fill the field, it may be hacked, etc...

The reliable way to process mime types is to check them on the actual file after it has been uploaded on your server.

The questions has been nicely discussed [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php) if you want to go for details.

Comment: +1 for official documentation link. "_some browsers just don't fill the field_": could you name some from top of your head? To know if it is common behavior to leave that field empty...

Comment: No, I can't : the common behavior is to fill the fields, I never met a browser no doing it... so far.

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever trust $_FILES['file']['type']. It takes whatever is sent from the browser. If you are concerned about security, use [finfo_open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) to verify the MIME type of the uploaded file.