# PHP: Why I can't download files with extensions "rar"?

Tags: php, download

I wrote this little PHP script for downloading files. It is working fine with the `"zip"` files but isn't able to download `"rar"` files.

Here is the script:

```
$file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.'ps-friend-redesigned'.'/' .$RESULT_ARRAY['bd_brushfilepath'];


function download_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
 if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found.');

 $size = filesize($file);
 $name = rawurldecode($name);

 $known_mime_types=array(
"pdf" => "application/pdf",
"txt" => "text/plain",
"html" => "text/html",
"htm" => "text/html",
"exe" => "application/octet-stream",
"zip" => "application/zip",
"doc" => "application/msword",
"xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
"ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"gif" => "image/gif",
"png" => "image/png",
"jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
"jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
"php" => "text/plain",
"rar" => "application/x-rar-compressed"
 );

 if($mime_type==''){
 $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
 if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
    $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
 } else{
     $mime_type="application/force-download";
 };
 };

 @ob_end_clean(); 

 if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
 ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

 header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; file="'.$name.'"');
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
 header("Cache-control: private");
 header('Pragma: private');
 readfile($file); 
}
```

Now, when I try to download `"rar"` files, it downlaods a PHP file with content `Rar!`with two squares following it. And, the size of this PHP file is equal to the actual RAR file. I tried to exclude `"rar" => "application/x-rar-compressed"` from this `$known_mime_types` array, but it still doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out the problem at all.

**UPDATE:**

I tried this code to get mime type(code copied from one of the answers here).

```
function get_mime($file) {
  if (function_exists("finfo_file")) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
    finfo_close($finfo);
    return $mime;
  } else if (function_exists("mime_content_type")) {
    return mime_content_type($file);
  } else if (!stristr(ini_get("disable_functions"), "shell_exec")) {
     // http://stackoverflow.com/a/134930/1593459
    $file = escapeshellarg($file);
    $mime = shell_exec("file -bi " . $file);
return $mime;
  } else {
   return false;
 }
```

}

I'm getting nothing if I echo result of this function.

Comment: The size of PHP file which is getting downloaded is equal to the size of the actual RAR file. But it downloads as a PHP file :(

Comment: `application/octet-stream` is probably more reliable

Comment: @Dagon, you mean I should replace whole array with this?

Comment: no just the mime type

Comment: @Dagon, tried it. Still doesn't work.. Anything else you can suggest?

Comment: Sounds like the server you are downloading from is misconfigured, and there is nothing wrong with your code per se (apart from the atrocious language you have chosen :-)

Comment: if you rename the file you get to .rar does it work as an archive?

Comment: @triplee I guess so. because I am not able to get mime type at all. Now, How to correct it?

Comment: If it's your server, fix the MIME type mappings.  If it's somebody else's, contact the site owner.  To obtain diagnostics, get the HTTP headers from a download and find the `Content-type:` and/or `Content-disposition:` headers and verify that they map to the wrong MIME type.

Comment: @triplee It's my own server. where do I fix the MIME type mappings ?

Comment: Why do you call the file which is getting downloaded _a PHP file_?

Comment: @Armali, because that file has .php extension.

Comment: It could be helpful if you displayed the arguments with which you call the function `download_file()`.

Comment: @Armali Thanks for your concern but the problem is solved. The problem was with the server and not this code.