# Why does this pattern not work in preg_match

Tags: preg-match

I use `preg_match` in a function to prevent image extensions from being submitted! 
Now I want to block " **~** " character also! 
Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

```
function is_valid($url) {
    $res = 1;
    if (isset($url['path'])) {
        if (preg_match('/\b.jpg\b/i', $url['path'])) { $res = 0; }
        if (preg_match('/\b.gif\b/i', $url['path'])) { $res = 0; }
        if (preg_match('/\b.png\b/i', $url['path'])) { $res = 0; }
        if (preg_match('/\b.bmp\b/i', $url['path'])) { $res = 0; }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
if (strpos('~', $url['path'])) {
    $res = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should really read something about regular expressions! If you have done that, read the [manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) for phps `strpos`.

You may try `preg_match('/[^~]+\.(png|jpg|gif|bmp)/i', $url['path'])` or if you want to stick to your version,

```
if (strpos($url['path'], '~') !== FALSE) {
    $res = 0;
}
```

But anyway, your check will just not be very safe. Example: Someone renames a php file into png and uploads it, if you have mime_magic activated on your apache, the code will get executed. So it is much safer to check the mimetype of the file. See [How do I find the mime-type of a file with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php) as an example. The accepted answer there mentions a (now) deprecated function, but you can use http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php if you have PHP 5.3+

Comment: Wow ! Your Codes Works :)
Thanks You for taking time out to answer this silly question. I greatly appreciate the assistance.
I'm Just a Newbie and trying to learn coding ! i'll definitely follow your instructions !
Thank You Again :) @Michael