# Checking "Magic Bytes" or Mime Types in PHP?

Tags: php, mime-types, magic-numbers

So, I've currently used a few different methods to check the mime type. The user uploads a file using a form, I grab the mime type, if it's application/zip, I allow it, if it's anything else, I deny it. The issue is that something (browsers I assume) is changing the mime type to "application/octet-stream"

I'm wondering how else I can verify a file is .zip upon form upload.

Code:

```
  $name = strtolower(end(explode('.', $filename))); 
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed',   'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed'); 

  foreach($accepted_types as $good_type) { 
        if($good_type == $type) {   
            $okay = true;  
            break;
        } else {
            $okay = false;
        }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the mime-type of a file with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php)

Comment: there shouldn't be anything changing the file content-type to application octet-stream in a form post. can you show how your handling the upload please

Comment: also you can do `in_array($type, $accepted_types);` you don't need a loop.

Comment: This is not answer question only one hint:you can use this code `$name=strtolower(pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));` for get extension file instead `$name = strtolower(end(explode('.', $filename)));`

Answer (score 4):

Use [mime-content-type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php).

```
$type = mime_content_type($filename);
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, you can get the magic bytes using `bin2hex`. According to Wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files), zips have the first 2 hex bytes `50` `4B`

`$zip=file_get_contents("somefile.zip");`

`echo strtoupper (substr(bin2hex($zip),0,2)); //504B`

Comment: Reading the whole zip file into memory, just to verify the magic bytes, is wasteful. Also, 4 characters, not 2.

`$F=fopen("somefile.zip","r");`

`$magic=fread($F,2);`

`fclose($F);`

`echo strtoupper(substr(bin2hex($magic),0,4)); //504B`