# file_exist displaying image path instead of .jpg

Tags: php

I got a code here using file_exist. it checks if a .txt and a .jpg file exist in the directory. and then displays those in an alert box. it works well for the .txt but not in the .jpg. it displays the image source instead of the image itself. what am i doing wrong here? can you give me some help regarding this? thanks a lot in advance! here's my code.

search.php

```
<?php
    class Model
    {
        public function readexisting()
        {
            if(
                file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Alchemy/events/folder-01/event-01.txt") 
                && 
                file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Alchemy/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg")
            )
            {  
                $myPic     =   "/Alchemy/ajax/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg";
                echo $myPic;

                $myFile    =   ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Alchemy/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
                $fh        =   fopen($myFile, 'r');
                $theData   =   fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
                fclose($fh);

                echo $theData ;
            }
            else
            {
                echo "The file $myFile does not exist";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Mark an answer as correct if you got your answer. This way you help other people save time and help other people in the community.

Comment: Hi! i tried the code you edited but i still get "/Alchemy/ajax/events/folder-01/event-01.jpg" being echoed instead of the .jpg file. do you have any other suggestions? thanks

Comment: Please read below this comment. There are three persons (including me) that gave you answers. Did you add header content type ?

Comment: yes but it's returning a warning. please edit my code again. so i would know the right way. i'm really having a hard time on this. i've been working on it for hours. i would really appreciate your effort.thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply `header()` and tell `PHP` that you are rendering an image.

`header("Content-type: image/jpeg");`

OR depending upon which file you are rendering, apply proper headers.

Comment: hi where excatly can i pplace the header()? thanks can you give me some codes regarding the proper headers to be used? thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `echo $myPic;` and then add this before the `echo $theData;`

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

In general you have to inform the browser for the data type you are sending. Also note, that the header() command should be located before you start sending any data to the browser.

Also, if you will manipulate multiple file types (ie: png, jpg, gif) you should change the MIME type in the deader command to map the appropriate file type.

```
header("Content-type: image/gif");   // For gif images
header("Content-type: image/png");   // For png images
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");   // For jpg images
```

Comment: hi i tried your suggestion. i deleted echo $myPic; and then added your code but it displays something like 'Warning: '

Comment: can you edit my code for me? so i can kanow exactly... im really having a hard time with this one. thanks

Comment: please consider that i need to display both. and also if you can put it already in a modal pop up.

Answer (score 0):

For an image (or anything else for that matter) you'll need to send a content-type header, otherwise it will not be shown. You can do this by getting the mime-type first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php) and then adding the header by doing this before the echo.

```
header("Content-Type: ". $mimetype);
echo $theData;
```

Where `$mimetype` is the mime type retrieved.