# Mime type not working

Tags: php, mime-types

I have searched mime types for zip,apk files but they are not working for me (gives error -invalid format as per my code written.) . I have following code with me , other mime types of allowed extensions are working perfectly.Whats going wrong for me in below code ?

```
$USER = $_COOKIE['phne'];
include 'config.php';

$sqli="SELECT * FROM `table*` WHERE EMAIL='$USER'";

$permquery=mysql_query($sqli);

$rows[35]=mysql_fetch_assoc($permquery);
echo '<a href="#"><img src="imagelogo*"></a><br>';
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" , "3gp" , "mp3" , "mp4", "apk", "zip"); 
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == 

"image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == 

"image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]

["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/3gpp") || ($_FILES

["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4") || 

($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/vnd.android.package-archive") || ($_FILES

 ["file"]["type"] == "'application/x-zip-compressed' , 'application/octet-stream' , 

 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed'") ) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 

  1500000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) 
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{ echo "Return Code: <a><b>" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "</a></b><br>"; }
else 
    {
 echo " <h1>Your Upload Status</h1><br>";
echo " Dear, "; 
 echo "<a><b>"; 
echo $rows[35][FNAME]." ".$rows[35][LNAME];
echo "</b></a>";
echo " Your Uploaded file is : <a><b>" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "</a></b><br>";
echo "Uploded file Format is: <a><b>" . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "</a></b><br>";
echo "Your file Size is: ";
echo "<a><b>"; 
 echo ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) ; 
  echo " KB <br></a></b>";  
  echo "<br>";
 echo "Your Email connected is ";
 echo "<a><b>";
echo $USER ;
echo "</a></b><br>";

 if (file_exists("location*/" . $USER . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) 
 {  echo " <h1>Final Status</h1><br><b>Sorry Upload failed.</b><br><a><b>File 

    already exists,Use different name .</b></a>"; 
     exit(); 
  } 
     else 
      {  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "location*/" . $USER . "/" . 

  $_FILES["file"]["name"]);  echo "<h1>Final Status</h1><br><b>Successfully Stored 

    to Kelkars.com :</b><br> " . "Your Successfully Uploaded File-"; 
     echo "<a><b>"; 
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       exit();
           } 
     }
   } 
      else { echo "<a>Invalid file-Sorry,This file Format not supported</a>";  
  exit();
    }
```

Any help would be Thank full.

Comment: it was suggested for me , so added that tag . though i removed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try printing the File Type returned by apk and zip**

try below method too ⇩

add this to

```
application/vnd.android.package-archive     apk
application/zip  zip

AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk
AddType application/zip  .zip
```

the file mime.types is located at 
{APACHE_INSTALL_PATH}/conf/ , and add the AddType line in httpd.conf near other AddType lines
add this to /etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf :

Comment: thanks for your answer , i got it but not fully understood how to open  the apache install path ?, im sorry im a learner , though will understand if you explain,. thank you , :)

Comment: it must be in your c drive

Comment: if you are using wamp server than try this path  
wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf

Comment: what is the path for c drive like C:\.....????. no dont have wamp server, but will port soon .

Comment: you can search file directly from search box

Answer (score 0):

According to [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) `type` isn't reliable information (it's sent from browser):

> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be "image/gif". This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

So basically... The issue is on the browsers side, not on servers side, but you can [check the file type manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php).

Comment: ohhhh is that the thing ? . well i use google chrome .

Comment: Manual says it's mime type recognized by browser... And user can always purposely fake the information.