# Finding Image MIME type

Tags: php, mime-types

I'm having no luck getting the MIME type of an uploaded image before that image is saved into a database. I've read books and dozens of web pages but cannot find an answer.

How can I determine the MIME type?

Here's the code I currently have. I've removed the various attempts at determining the MIME type:

```
$upload_dir = HOST_WWW_ROOT . "uploads/movie_pics/";
$image_fieldname = "movie_pic";

// Name the file uniquely
$now = time();
while (file_exists($upload_filename = $upload_dir . $now .
                                 '-' .
                                 $_FILES[$image_fieldname]['name'])) {
$now++;
}

// Insert the image into the movies_images table
$image = $_FILES[$image_fieldname];
$movie_images_filename = $image['name'];
$movie_images_info = getimagesize($image['tmp_name']);

$finfo = finfo_open();
$movie_images_mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $upload_filename, FILEINFO_MIME);
finfo_close($finfo);


$movie_images_size = $image['size'];
$movie_images_data = file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']);

$insert_image_sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO movies_images " .
            "(movie_images_filename, movie_images_mime_type, movie_images_file_size,  movie_images_data) " .
                        "VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, '%s');",
                        mysql_real_escape_string($movie_images_filename),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($movie_images_mime_type),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($movie_images_size),
                        mysql_real_escape_string($movie_images_data));

mysql_query($insert_image_sql)
```

or die(mysql_error());

Comment: `$movie_images_info['mime']` should return the image MIME type.

Comment: Check [image_type_to_mime_type](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134833/how-do-i-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-with-php)?

Comment: Rahil, that was the first way I tried to do it, but when I look into the database after the data is inserted, no mime type is saved. that field is always empty. Everything else saves but that. I believe that it may have something to do with newer versions of PHP not being able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you will only ever be dealing with images you can use the [`exif_imagetype()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php).

The below code will compare a file to a particular IMAGE type. It then uses [`image_type_to_mime_type()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) to retrieve the file's mime-type using the image type stored in $image_type.

**Example 1 (extracted from link above)**

```
// if file is a GIF line below should return IMAGETYPE_GIF
$image_type = exif_imagetype('image.gif'); 

if ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {
    $mime = image_type_to_mime_type(); // will produce "image/gif" as String.
    echo 'The picture is a gif, with a mime type of ' . $mime;
}
```

**Do NOT use mysql_* for new code.**

Also, it is advised to no longer use **mysql_*** functions for new code, as it has been deprecated. I would recommend looking into [**mysqli_***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) forms of MySQL querying.

Comment: Can you better explain this?

Comment: Edited with better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual page of [finfo_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) the example passes the const FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE to finfo_open, rather than finfo_file.

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
$movie_images_mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $upload_filename);
```

Comment: I've been trying this, but something doesn't work. It seems that $upload_filename ceases to exist? I move the code around, but no luck.